# The application failed to initialize properly on Windows xp

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, winsock

I have written and [Windows LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_Service_Provider) aaplication which works fine on windows 7 but it gives following error on windows xp "The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0000142)"
I am not able to understand the reason why its not working.

On looking using dependecy walker I found secur32.dll and ws2help.dll that are loaded in xp and not on win7
Can anyone tell me what may be the reason?

Comment: were you running depends in profile mode?

Comment: [Loader snaps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2006/11/20/debugging-loadlibrary-failures.aspx) will probably tell you exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually result of missing C++ runtime libraries. Find VC++ redistributable package and install it on target computer. It can be downloaded from Microsoft: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=29 or http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=15336.

If you have installation project, VC++ redistributable can be added to it as prerequisite or merge module.